# expand to menu item size

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

how can i expand to menu item?

below code is example of CCMenu but i can't find to expand to each one of menu item size

```
// Create some menu items
CCMenuItemImage * menuItem1 = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"myfirstbutton.png"
selectedImage: @"myfirstbutton_selected.png"
target:self
selector:@selector(doSomethingOne:)];

CCMenuItemImage * menuItem2 = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"mysecondbutton.png"
selectedImage: @"mysecondbutton_selected.png"
target:self
selector:@selector(doSomethingTwo:)];

CCMenuItemImage * menuItem3 = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"mythirdbutton.png"
selectedImage: @"mythirdbutton_selected.png"
target:self
selector:@selector(doSomethingThree:)];

// Create a menu and add your menu items to it
CCMenu * myMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:menuItem1, menuItem2, menuItem3, nil];

// Arrange the menu items vertically
[myMenu alignItemsVertically];
```

Comment: what do you mean by "expand"?

Answer (score 0):

Change your images size and use new expanded images....

Answer (score 0):

There is a property setScale which you can use to expand or reduce the actual scale(size) of that particular Menu Item. For example you can do this by

```
[menuItem1 setScale:1.5];
```

This method can also be used with any CCSprite object.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to expand,

1) You can scale :

```
[menuItem1 setScale:1.5];
```

2) You can use replace with large images, CCMenuItem automatically detects the size of the image and set its touchable area. For iPhone version, according to me every button should have minimum size 30 X 30 Pixel, otherwise it will be hard to press the button as user point of view.

3) You can increase the conetent size, even if your image size of small,

```
[menuitem1 setContentSize:Size];
```